# Can Persistent Search Options be Used in MarkLogic JSearch?

Tags: marklogic

Is it possible to use pre-defined, persistent Search Options within JSearch, similar to the Search REST API? Looking through the documentation, I was not able to find it out.

JSearch: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/javascript

Query Options: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/query-options

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly. You would have to traverse the options, and construct the search with facets and all yourself. It would not be too hard though. Below a quick attempt. I downloaded existing search options via `GET /v1/config/query/all?format=json`, and isolated a few path index facets. Here some code that traverses them, and produces facet values:

```
'use strict';

const jsearch = require('/MarkLogic/jsearch.sjs');

function reference(c) {
  if (c.range) {
    if (c.range['path-index']) {
      return cts.pathReference(c.range['path-index'].text)
    }
  }
}

const options = {
    "options": {
        "constraint": [{
            "name": "Auteur",
            "range": {
                "type": "xs:string",
                "facet": true,
                "collation": "http://marklogic.com/collation/codepoint",
                "facet-option": ["limit=10", "frequency-order", "descending"],
                "path-index": {
                    "text": "*:meta[@name = 'Author']/@content"
                }
            }
        }, {
            "name": "ContentType",
            "range": {
                "type": "xs:string",
                "facet": true,
                "collation": "http://marklogic.com/collation/codepoint",
                "facet-option": ["limit=10", "frequency-order", "descending"],
                "path-index": {
                    "text": "*:meta[@name = 'content-type']/@content"
                }
            }
        }]
    }
};

const facets = options.options.constraint.filter(c => c.range);

jsearch.facets(
  facets.map(f => {
    let ref = reference(f);
    if (ref) {
      return jsearch.facet(f.name, ref);
    }
  }).filter(f => f)
).result('iterator');
```

HTH!

Comment: Thanks, @grtjn. I feel it would be nice if JSearch can have a built-in method to directly consume search options for better interoperability with other search utilities in MarkLogic. Or am I misusing JSearch for something it is not designed for?

Comment: The older search:search library comes with XML search options, and is very much focussed around XQuery code/customizations, which is an unnatural fit for JavaScript. That is why JSearch was created, which is only available for JavaScript. It is particularly the customization hooks that make it difficult to provide one standard for both worlds.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.